Ruby & Rails available in Linux Mint terminal, but not available in RubyMine's terminal
Summary
On my machine, Ruby and Rails are only available in Linux Mint standalone terminal, but not available in RubyMine's integrated terminal. I suspect it's related to RubyMine's terminal not using login shell.
Details
I'm on Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon. I installed Ruby using rvm, then installed Rails using gem:

However, if I were to run the same commands in RubyMine's terminal (which is also /bin/bash), I can't find those:

Interestingly, if I were to turn off "login shell" in the native terminal:

I would get the same result:

Questions

What is this "login shell", and why are Ruby and Rails only available in login shell on mode? Is it because I installed it in that mode?
How should I make Ruby & Rails command available in RubyMine's terminal? I didn't find a way to turn on login shell in RubyMine's settings so I can't verify that it is indeed the cause. Should I just install Ruby & Rails again in login shell off mode?


See What are the differences between a login shell and interactive shell?. In this case the key difference is most likely that your path variable and rbenv init are not initialized when Rubymine launches the shell - what executable it is doesn't matter as much as how it's launched.

There should be an option called Shell Integration which should source the same bootstrap files as a login shell. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-terminal.html#application-settings

Also make sure you have the correct Ruby version selected in Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems
